# Changing window.location within a POST ajax handler issues a new ajax call instead of redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've reached the need to centralize how I do ajax calls in order to deal with session timeouts in a single place. So, I have a function that looks like such:

```
function doAjax(settings) {
    var innerSuccess = function(response) {
        if(response.indexOf("{logout test string}") > -1){
            window.location = {login page url};
            return;
        }
    }

    if(settings.success) {
        var successFunc = settings.success;
        innerSuccess = function(response) {
            ... same if statement from above ...
            successFunc(response);
        }
    }

    settings.success = innerSuccess;

    $.ajax(settings);
}
```

In the above, instead of just setting `window.location`, I've also tried setting `window.location.href`, using `window.location.assign(..)`, and `window.location.replace(..)`. No matter what I do, though, I end up staying on the page, and Chrome's Network debugger shows the login page redirect I'm trying to perform as just another ajax call instead of taking me to that URL. To test this, I do the following:

1. Login to my site normally to create a valid user session
2. Navigate to the page where this code exists
3. Open the Chrome debugging tools
4. Do one call through my `doAjax` method to make sure it works normally
5. I can see this call fine on the Network tab - all looks good and `type` is `xhr`
6. Open task manager
7. Kill the IIS process (this is a .Net site)
8. Make the call from step 4 again, only this time I can see the network redirection on the Network tab but its `type` is also `xhr` and I stay on the same page

There's nothing in this that tries to make the page change domains. Currently, this is all localhost, anyway. I've verified the conditions I'm looking for in my code sample is correct with the console. I can even see the `GET` for the login page URL complete with Status 200.

To be clear, the intended function of my code is fine if the initial ajax call is a `GET`, and this behavior only happens with the initial request is a `POST`.

Can I change this behavior?

Here's a rough example of what I'm passing to `doAjax` based on an actual call.

```
window.doAjax({
    url: "http://localhost/Foo/Bar",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "values" : barValues }),
    type: "POST",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#obj-id"). --- parse the response here ---
        $("#obj-parent-id").show();
    }
});
```

That's one of the examples that fails. One that works exactly as I'd expect looks like the following.

```
window.doAjax({
    url: "http://localhost/Foo/Baz",
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
        modal.dialog("close");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        --- parse xhr/status/error to formulate a message to alert ---
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var pane = --- build an element based on what's contained in data ---
        $("#panes").append(pane);
        loadedPanes.push(data.Name);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's because if you are passing to doAjax({ success: function() {} }), it will override innerSuccess() that is responsible for redirection.

Comment: @SergeyShvager That doesn't make sense as I can see the call being made in either case. For `GET` requests, the only difference that the window.location call is being handled as another ajax request. For `POST`, all is as I'd expect.

Comment: It'll be better to see the parameters that you are passing to doAjax()

Comment: @SergeyShvager I've added two examples: one that fails and one that works.

Comment: @SergeyShvager Also, in my other comment, I switched the scenarios. Sorry! `POST` is the one with weird behavior. `GET`s work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came down to the fact that, based on my observations, in scenarios where I'd be logged out and the browser and server would do a 302 behind the scenes (from the perspective of the XHR object) to respond with the login page, these are not handled by the success handler. These are handled by the complete handler.